# How are the various ulimit values for a process set?

Tags: user-management, ulimit, ps

How are the various `ulimit` values for a process set? I am especially interested in the number of open file descriptors. How is that set for a given process? If it is based on the user who started the process then how is it set for the user?

How can I set these limits for a particular user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have not changed the value of any resource shown by `ulimit`, it would use the default value which is what you see while running the shell built-in `ulimit -a`. Note that the system call inolved in getting the value is `getrlimit(2)`.

Again if you need to change the value you need to use `setrlimit(2)` system call, `ulimit` does exactly this while setting a new resoure limit for processes.

The resource limits shown in `ulimit` are applied on individual processes, not users.

To set the new value for the number of open file descriptors (default is 1024) per process, you can use :

```
ulimit -n 512
```

Note that you can check the hard limit and soft limits with `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn` respectively. You can decrease to any value and increase upto the hard limit.

To increase the limit beyond current hard limit (1024) you need to be root.

Note that you can not increase the value beyond kernel specified maximum.

Now there is a file `/etc/security/limits.conf` that is used by `pam` specifically `pam_limits.so` upon start of each user session, you can set values here to take permanent effect as `ulimit` set values only for the running session.

Although you need to set the values on this file on a user/group basis the limits are applicable on per process under that user/group apart from some items like `maxsyslogins`, `maxlogins`. `/etc/security/limits.conf` has sufficient description within the file to get you started.

Also check `help ulimit`, `man 2 setrlimit` to get more idea.

Answer (score -4):

It's POSIX - see `man 3 sysconf`

```
NAME
       sysconf - get configuration information at run time

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       long sysconf(int name);

DESCRIPTION
       POSIX  allows  an  application  to  test at compile or run time whether
       certain options  are  supported,  or  what  the  value  is  of  certain
       configurable constants or limits.

       At  compile time this is done by including <unistd.h> and/or <limits.h>
       and testing the value of certain macros.

       At run time, one  can  ask  for  numerical  values  using  the  present
       function  sysconf().   One can ask for numerical values that may depend
       on the filesystem a  file  is  in  using  the  calls  fpathconf(3)  and
       pathconf(3).  One can ask for string values using confstr(3).

       The  values  obtained  from  these  functions  are system configuration
       constants.  They do not change during the lifetime of a process.  

       ...<snip>... 

       OPEN_MAX - _SC_OPEN_MAX
              The  maximum number of files that a process can have open at any
              time.  Must not be less than _POSIX_OPEN_MAX (20).
```

Comment: Yes, it does. The manual explains it very well and includes files and options possible to use. Though the answer *does* lack substance so I went for a VLQ :-P

Comment: waltinator, could you please copy the relevant part of the man page in your answer?  You're showing up in the low quality review queue (I voted "looks OK", but with mixed feelings)  **:p ;-)**

Comment: @Rinzwind given the quoted section of the manpage, I don't think so.